# How do I prepare a statement with VARBINARY in PHP PDO for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, varbinary

This is the code that I'm using to try comparing to a `VARBINARY` using PHP PDO:

```
$st = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `xf_ip` WHERE user_id = ? AND ip = ?;');
$st ->execute(array($new_row[':forums_id'], $hexip));
```

I tried prefacing it with `0x` (`'0x' . $hexip`), as well as using `bindParam`:

```
$st = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `xf_ip` WHERE user_id = :user_id AND ip = :ip;');
$st->bindParam(':user_id', $new_row[':forums_id'], \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindParam(':ip', $hexip, \PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$st->execute();
```

This is the only query that works, but it's an unsafe query because it's not prepared and could be vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
$st = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `xf_ip` WHERE user_id = ' . (int) $new_row[':forums_id'] . ' AND ip = 0x' . $hexip);
```

The hexip has to be in the format `0xFFFFFFFF` with no quotes, and not in integer format, otherwise MySQL will not accept it.

Is this not possible with PDO?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621862/insert-varbinary-data-on-mysql-table-via-php to see if this helps.

Comment: There is nothing special in varbinary fields. You just compare them like any other data. Where did you get that $hexip and why it hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters always act as if you had passed them as a string, at least in the MySQL PDO driver. The eight-character string 'FFFFFFFF' is not equal to the 4-byte binary string represented by 0xFFFFFFFF. The following two SQL statements are NOT the same:

```
SELECT * FROM `xf_ip` WHERE user_id = :user_id AND ip = 0xFFFFFFFF
SELECT * FROM `xf_ip` WHERE user_id = :user_id AND ip = 'FFFFFFFF'
```

But passing 'FFFFFFFF' as your parameter executes a statement like the latter one.

There are two solutions:

One is to pass a string of hex digits, but use UNHEX() in SQL to convert those hex digits to the equivalent binary string before you compare it to your column:

```
SELECT * FROM `xf_ip` WHERE user_id = :user_id AND ip = UNHEX(:ip)
```

The other solution is to pass a binary string, after first un-hexing it in PHP:

```
$binip = hex2bin($hexip);
$st->bindParam(':ip', $binip, \PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much. This issue has been driving me crazy since the beginning of December. Jokes on me for thinking bindParam would automatically convert a PHP hexadecimal integer to binary.

Comment: If it did that, how would you ever search for a literal string that happens to be comprised of the digits 0-9 and letters A-F? :-)

Comment: Well, I was providing an integer after converting it with `dechex` to hexadecimal and the bind type `\PDO::PARAM_LOB`, so I thought it would convert it to binary, not take it as a string. I actually forgot that I could manipulate raw binary in PHP.